# what are the best practices to use python in c# application?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have a requirement for using Python analytics into c# application.

To be precise: c# should call a python script and get the output back into c# application for further processing.

I have tried using IronPython as recommend by many.

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.ExecuteFile(@"DemoPythonApplication\SentimentAnalysis.py", scope);

dynamic testFunction = scope.GetVariable("create_sentiment_analysis"); //calling a function from python script file
var result = testFunction(); //This function is returning a dynamic dictionary, which I can use in my c# code further
```

But the limitation with IronPython is, it is not providing support for many python libraries like pandas, numpy, nltk etc, These libraries are getting used in python scripts. (since we have a different team working on python I don't have control over them for using specific libraries.)

Another option i tried is to run the python process and calling the script

```
private static readonly string PythonLocation = @"Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"; //Location of Python.exe
private static readonly string PythonScript = @"DemoPythonApplication\SentimentAnalysis.py"; //Location of Python Script

private static void ProcessInPython(int a, int b)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = PythonLocation;
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", PythonScript, a, b);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are limitations of using this approach though, I am only able to get whatever is getting printed on the console as a `string`, and could not get the output that python functions are returning.

Also if I use the 2nd approach, I don't know how to call a specific function from the python script file.

Can someone help with the best practices of using python in c# for this kind of situation?